# OneDrive / SharePoint disable suggestion share user name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business

I am wondering if it is possible to disable the setting that stops OneDrive/SharePoint from suggesting search results. This means that users can only share with people whose correct email addresses they type.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible.

Someone has previously made the same request as you, please check it out:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-turn-off-the-email-suggest-when-file-sharing/m-p/1091705

If you want Microsoft to implement it in modern experience, you can submit new idea on [SharePoint Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472). Microsoft will take your idea into consideration if it is highly voted.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.